# $\overline{\left\{ϕ∈C_c^∞(Λ)^d:∇⋅u=0\right\}}^{\left\|\;⋅\;\right\|_{H_0^1(Λ,\:ℝ^d)}}=\left\{u∈H_0^1(Λ,ℝ^d):∇⋅u=0\right\}$

Tags: functional-analysis, fluid-dynamics

Let

- $d\in\mathbb N$
- $\Lambda\subseteq\mathbb R^d$ be open
- $\mathcal V:=\left\{\phi\in C_c^\infty(\Lambda)^d:\nabla\cdot u=0\right\}$
- $\tilde V:\left\{u\in H_0^1(\Lambda,\mathbb R^d):\nabla\cdot u=0\right\}$

It's easy to see that $$V:=\overline{\mathcal V}^{\left\|\;\cdot\;\right\|_{H_0^1(\Lambda,\:\mathbb R^d)}}\subseteq\tilde V\;.\tag 1$$ Under the assumption that $\Lambda$ is bounded $\partial\Lambda$ is Lipschitz, I was able to show that for each $\eta\in\tilde V'$ with $\left.\eta\right|_V=0$, we've got $\eta=0$.

> Why can we conclude that $V=\tilde V$?

Maybe it's a consequence by the Hahn-Banach theorem. If we equip $\tilde V$ with the norm induced by $H_0^1(\Lambda,\mathbb R^d)$, it should be a normed space and $V$ should be a subspace of $\tilde V$. By the statement about the $\eta\in\tilde V'$ above, the Hahn-Banach theorem would yield that $V$ is dense in $\tilde V$.

Is that the correct argumentation? And if so, why does the density of $V$ in $\tilde V$ yield $V=\tilde V$?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Show that the closure of $\left\{ϕ∈C_c^∞(Ω)^n:∇⋅ϕ=0\right\}$ in $H^1(Ω,ℝ^d)$ is $\left\{u∈H_0^1(Ω,ℝ^n):∇⋅u=0\right\}$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1891203/show-that-the-closure-of-left-%cf%95%e2%88%88c-c%e2%88%9e%ce%a9n%e2%88%87%e2%8b%85%cf%95-0-right-in-h1%ce%a9-%e2%84%9dd-is)

Comment: @FourierTransform It's not a duplicate. The other question (deleted now) asked for the proof of the statement about the $\eta\in\tilde V'$.